# Java EE's CDI doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

Hi everyone I have the following code trying to use **CDI**'s `@produces`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
public class ConnectionSupplier
{

    @Produces
    //@RequestScoped
    @Connect
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        //get connection from datasource
    }
}
```

And this is `@connect` Qualifier

```
//remove imports

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Connect{}
```

and here we make **injection**

```
import com.seta.history.db.entities.Day;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@RequestScoped
@Named("day")
public class DayController
{

    @Inject
    @Connect
    private Connection connection;
    public void save(Day day)
    {
        //do-save
    }
}
```

but it gives the following exception

```
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing 
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment                 
failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Connection with     
qualifiers @Connect
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Connect private 
com.seta.history.db.controllers.DayController.connection
at 
com.seta.history.db.controllers.
     DayController.connection(DayController.java:0)
```

I am using **Java EE 7** + **GlassFish 4.1.2**

**NOTE** we usually used Glassfish and **CDI** and it works fine

so can anyone help And thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any beans.xml? Which version of CDI? Looks like `ConnectionSupplier` is not scanned by CDI. Can you try adding `@ApplicationScoped` on `ConnectionSupplier` class?

Comment: Make sure the class where you declare CDI producer is itself a bean (otherwise CDI won't detect the producer). Furthermore, make sure the producer itself does not return `null`. If the produced bean is `@Dependent` (which is your case), `null` can be returned, which would then result in failed injection.

Comment: @Rouliboy @Siliarus Thank you, you are completely right I didn't have `bean.xml` file so I created it and added this line  `bean-discovery-mode="all"` so it worked fine I think the **CDI container**  didn't deal with `ConnectionSupplier` as a bean

Comment: @Anas : that's it. In CDI > 1.0, if you do not have any beans.xml, CDI only scans annotated class. (That's why it would have workded if you has annotated your bean with @ApplicationScoped).

Comment: Can you post a detailed answer to be marked as accepted so may others can benefit? @Rouliboy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CDI > 1.0, if you do not have any beans.xml, CDI only scans annotated classes. So CDI does not take into account your `ConnectionSupplier` class and the producer.

You have two ways to correct this :

- Annotate your `ConnectionSupplier` class (for example with `@ApplicationScoped`)
- Add a `beans.xml` with `bean-discovery-mode="all"` to tell CDI to scan all classes.